# Problems with rsGetElementAt_uchar4

Tags: renderscript

I'm trying to implement a median filter in RenderScript. But the work of the code is not stable. Reading elements not from the current line rsGetElementAt_uchar4 (inputAlloc, x , y + a ) causes errors. What is the problem ? Is there an example of such a filter using RenderScript?

```
    #pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(a.myapplication)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed


rs_allocation inputAlloc;
int bWidht, bHeight;

static uchar4 arrpix[9];
static uchar4 buff;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) median(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{

uchar4 arrpix[9];
uchar4 buff;

                      if((x<bWidht) && (y<bHeight)){
        arrpix[0] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x -1 , y - 1);
        arrpix[1] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x    , y - 1);
        arrpix[2] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x +1 , y - 1);


        arrpix[3] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x -1 , y    );
        arrpix[4] = in;
        arrpix[5] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x +1 , y    );

        arrpix[6] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x -1 , y + 1);
        arrpix[7] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x    , y + 1);
        arrpix[8] = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inputAlloc, x +1 , y + 1);


for(int i=0; i<4; i++)

for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){

if(arrpix[i].r>arrpix[i+1].r){
buff.r = arrpix[i].r; arrpix[i].r = arrpix[i+1].r;
arrpix[i+1].r = buff.r;}

if(arrpix[i].g>arrpix[i+1].g){
buff.g = arrpix[i].g; arrpix[i].g = arrpix[i+1].g;
arrpix[i+1].g = buff.g;}

if(arrpix[i].b>arrpix[i+1].b){
buff.b = arrpix[i].b; arrpix[i].b = arrpix[i+1].b;
arrpix[i+1].b = buff.b;}

}
}
    return arrpix[4];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check x>0 and y>0 because 0-1 =-1

Bottom loops don't look completely correct either. Can you fix the spacing and did you mean to use i in both loops?